# Distance between triangle and a point in 2D

Tags: geometry, distance

I am trying to calculate the shortest distance between a point and a triangle.

I tried the following,
1. Calculate the centroid of triangle.
2. Form a line between the centroid and the point.
3. Find which side of triangle is intersection with the above formed line.
4. Find the perpendicular distance between the point and the intersecting line found in step (3).

Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone help me in getting the distance?

Comment: This is not, as asked, programming related.